# package clash: fontenc package with lilypond environment

Tags: font-encodings, lilypond

I'm working with lilypond (`lyluatex` package) within LaTeX to write scores.
I'm using a wide variety of packages within my file (as you can see below and they're all used in the original document), but now when I wanted to make my chapters "look nice", the fontenc package wouldn't be compatible with the lilypond enviroment.
It would be great if someone would by able to help!

[image: this is what I want the chapter to look like (works when there is no lilypond enviroment in the file, but the package lyluatex is in the list)]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lyluatex}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%command for new chapter format
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hspace{20pt}\textcolor{gray}{|}\hspace{20pt}}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{test}
    \begin{lilypond}[staffsize=26]
      \score {
        \relative
          c''1
        }
      }
    \end{lilypond}
\end{document}
```

[image: And this is the error message I get with a lilypond enviroment in the file, which works perfectly without the fontenc package]

[image: The code as a picture, because the typed one looks weird how I see it at the moment...]

Everything was totally fine until I entered the fontenc package, the other ones work together well.

Comment: well you shouldn't use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with lualatex. Why did you add it?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I added it because I don't want to waste so much space on the first side of the chapter and have a simpler way to begin a new chapter like shown above

Comment: no idea what you mean. In any case don't use fontenc + T1 with lualatex. Beside this: your example already errors at the `\usepagacke`.

Comment: thx, just corrected it... as you see in my code it was right(picture)...

Why shouldn't I use those together and are there any other ways to make a smaller, nicer chapter?  The fcnychap package doesn't work either...

Comment: If you want a small chapter, why do you use `\Huge` in the titleformat declaration?

Comment: T1{fontenc} is unrelated to spacing and the layout, it just selects legacy 8 bit (T1) encoded fonts so should never be used with luatex, unrelated to lilypond

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle!
Could have tried it earlier using my command without this package ^^'

@UlrikeFischer: Wenn man das mit der Überschrift, die default ist vergleicht, hat man immer noch nur ein halbes bis ein drittel an Platz... Und die Überschrift ist trotzdem noch schön hervorgehoben

Answer (score 0):

As @DavidCarlisle said:
I just have to not use the `fontenc` package, because I do not need it as I thought based on the source I used for the command.
Thanks @David Carlisle! Now it works perfectly!